# MYSQLI sending random long integer instead of data passed via ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

**Edit**: I got it working by removing prepared statements. All files using prepared statements broke at the same time. Is there some sort of server setting change that could have created this fiasco? Current PHP settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVcap.jpg

This has stumped me for hours now. I am trying to submit a user submitted form via jquery into the database and it works except posted integer fields that are submitted are random integers 8 characters long instead of the values submitted. Strings from the form are not passing anything at all. When I define the variables manually above the mysqli it works correctly. The form/field names are also correctly named in the HTML. Oddly enough I remember this code was working around 5 months ago, but I have no idea what changed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I've noticed that another jquery form using the same method also broke which I know for a fact was working. It has the same issue of random integers being submitted. Lastly There is yet another form that does the same thing but without prepared statements which submits the data correctly.

PHP:

```
$urlId = $_POST['urlId'];
$giverId =  $_SESSION["mem_id"];
$receiverId = $_POST['receiverId'];
$feedback = $_POST['feedback'];

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $passwrd, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}           

if (!($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cc_feedback (url_id, giverId, receiverId, feedback, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param("iiis", $urlId, $giverId, $receiverId, $feedback)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

JS:

```
(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#feedback-form').submit(function(e){     
        e.preventDefault();     
        $.post('include/insertdata.php', $(this).serialize() )
        .done(function(data){
            // do stuffs
        })
        .fail(function(){
            //alert('Ya done');
        });     
    }); 
});
```

Database Entry:

If the form is submitted with the following fields:

- urlId: 123
- receiverId: 123
- feedback: testing
- giverId is session handled (we'll say 555 for user ID. This field works)

Then the data shows up in the DB as follows:

- urlId: 39361776
- receiverId: 39361904
- feedback: NULL
- giverId: 555

I checked that the data was passing to the file by setting the urlId to a separate session variable on the insertdata.php page. It shows up as the correct urlId (in this case 123)

Comment: What the headers says? May be your variables are overwritten.

Comment: I double checked the form variables are being successfully passed to the php file. When I output them into a table they are all correct.

Comment: Use your browser's _Network_ console to inspect the request, ie find the POST request to `insertdata.php`, click it and look at the _"form data"_ being submitted in the _"Headers"_ tab. Does it look correct?

Comment: The headers do indeed send the correct user submitted info - I did notice similar scripts without prepared statements are working correctly. Not sure if that is heading in the right direction

Comment: Any chance you could post a screenshot of the submitted form data? What debugging have you done on the server side? You could at least use `var_dump($_POST)` and see what you get. Also, how are you verifying the problem; how and where are you seeing the `39361776`, etc?

Comment: Just saw your edit, that's very strange. Could you perhaps try PDO instead of MySQLi?

Comment: Sure thing! Heres what I'm working with. https://imgur.com/a/M548PMk I have checked its passing variables correctly. It seems to be something with prepared statements. I'll give PDO a shot and see if binding params causes a similar issue

Comment: Ok so.. PDO prepared statements do the same thing except they also scramble the giverId as well! Which was the only one working with mysqli. I'm having trouble finding replications of this problem on google as well, it seems so odd

Comment: What data types are your columns? What collation? What [connection charset](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.set-charset.php) are you using? Try adding `var_dump($urlId, $giverId, $receiverId, $feedback);` both before and after you `execute()` the statement. What does it show?

Comment: Thank you Phil! So var dump before and after (they are the same) revealed that they were all strings, except $giverId of course. I converted $urlId and $receiverId into ints and they submit correctly! The only remaining issue is $feedback still not submitting dispite being a string variable in php / varchar in database. I'm not sure why the int conversions were needed though, I remember PHP usually coerces variables pretty well.